# Create new Database in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, database

I use the following code to create a new database in SQL Server 2008 R2, program language is VB.NET:

```
Dim WEBconnString As String = "Data Source='NewName'; LCID=1032; Case Sensitive = FALSE; SSCE:Database Password=NewDBpass; Encrypt = TRUE;"
Dim engine As New SqlCeEngine(WEBconnString)
engine.CreateDatabase()
```

Additionally:

I open a web server connection with the following instruction:

```
ServerConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=" & WebServerName & _
                         "; Database=master" & _
                         "; Uid=" & TempUserName & _
                         "; Pwd=" & TempUserPass
ServerConn.Open()
```

And I also use a data base connection with the following instruction:

```
SQLConn.ConnectionString = "server=" & WebServer & "; Uid=" & AdminName & "; Pwd=" & AdminPassword & "; database=master"
SQLConn.Open()
```

In order to be able to use my instruction. I have already create a temporary database in my ISP SQL Server, and I'm using for login name and password the credentials from this database.

For the first time use; it works fine, means that somewhere creates a database

Now I'm trying to see this database and I can't found anything

I'm running the same code again because it seams to me that the database not created, and at the engine instruction gives me an error "The database exist"

And the question is: Where it is opened the new database?

Please give me any solution I may need in VB.NET

Comment: It seems you are mixing *SqlServerCompact* (Local datatase, which can be used in ASP.NET since version 4.0) and *SqlServer*. `SqlCeEngine` is part of `System.Data.SqlServerCe` namespace. And then, you are using *OLEDB* in your connectionstring. I'm confused. What database are you trying to create exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) It seems you are mixing *SqlServerCompact* (Local datatase which can be used in ASP.NET since version 4.0) and *SqlServer*. `SqlCeEngine` is part of `System.Data.SqlServerCe` namespace. So you create a SqCompact file and the `engine.CreateDatabase()` method raises an exception the second time.
The connection string seems correct (for a SqlServerCompact file). If you don't specify the full path in your connection string (just set the database name like here), the database will be created where the `app.exe` is executed (=`|DirectoryPath|`). You will have to look for a file with `.sdf` extension.

2) I don't know what type is `ServerConn` but since I see `"Provider=SQLOLEDB;"` in your connection string, I guess your are using `OLEDB` class. You should use instead the managed SqlServer class (`System.Data.SqlServer` namespace). So you should use `SqlConnection` , `SqlCommand`, ..., objects. If you already use them, then check your [connectionstring](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) since the provider is wrong.
At any rate, you can't access to the file created first in 1) in both case.

3) If your goal is to create a SqlServer Datatase, unfortunatly, where is no `SqlServerEngine` class like in `SqlServerCe`.

To create a database, some possible ways:

- At design time with Sql Server Management studio
- By executing scrits (via Sql Server Management studio, Or via .Net code, ...)
- Using `System.Data.SqlServer.Smo` class (.Net)

Comment: I thing you're very close to what I thought. Something with the SqlServerCE may happen. Please tell me where I'll fount this .exe folder… In a previous version of database creation I was use a procedure of mine and that was because I have to use Streaming database. Now I want to use a simple database creation and I don’t have any procedure “ready to use” it. All the other issues are as you mention

Comment: In a Winforms project, the database is created by default in the `|DirectoryPath|` (where the `app.exe` is executed) if you specify only the database Name, it was what I meant). I don't know if this concept exists in ASP.NET. Maybe it is where the project is deployed. You will have to look for a file with `.sdf` extension. But I repeat, you can't access this database with this code wich is for SqlServer.

Comment: @LefterisGkinis So concerning `SQLServer` database creation, you should first make a choice between this solutions. Maybe I could add more links and references (and correct typos...), but I don't think my answer can cover all the possibilities, it's a bit broad...

Comment: Right now I'm looking for a procedure to create a database on my ISP SQL SERVER. For all the others you're very right. Thanks Chris

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are opening the Server connection the the master database. The master database is where the sql server engine keeps all the important information and meta data about all databases on that server.

I need to replace `database=master` to `database=WHATEVER DATABASE NAME YOU CREATED`. All else fails go to the sql server and run this

```
use master;
select * from sysdatabases
```

That will give you the name of every database that master is 'monitoring'. Find the one you tried to create and replace the `database=master` with `database=the one you found`

Comment: I'm looking in sys.database and the new name is nowhere.Teh master database is there and untouched everything in my ISP SQL SERVER works just fine. But my new database ?

Comment: If you are getting "the database exists" error and it doesnt show up in that query i gave you ,are you sure you are connecting to the right server? Also be very carefull in MASTER you can destroy SQL server instance pretty easily.

Comment: I'm sure for everything that you're telling me. And the database is not there. And the connection string is OK

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ready to use sub for creating a procudere:

```
Public Shared Sub CreateSP(ByVal usp As String, ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim RetValue As Boolean = False

        Try
            DBConnection("SQLConn", "SQLUSER", "master", False, sender, e)
            Select Case SQLConn.State
                Case ConnectionState.Open

                    MASQLComm = New SqlCommand("CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[" & usp & "]" & _
                      NewLine & " ( " & _
                      NewLine & "@DBName varchar(50) ) AS " & NewLine & _
                       "BEGIN_TRY: " & NewLine & " SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;" & NewLine & " SET NOCOUNT ON; " & _
                       NewLine & "DECLARE " & _
                       NewLine & "@ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), " & _
                       NewLine & "@CreateSdb nvarchar(4000)" & _
                       NewLine & "SET @CreateSdb =('CREATE DATABASE ' + @DBName )" & _
                       NewLine & "BEGIN_CATCH:" & NewLine & "SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage;" & _
                       NewLine & "SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE()" & _
                       NewLine & "EXEC sp_executesql @CreateSdb" & _
                       NewLine & "RAISERROR (@ErrMsg,2,1)" & _
                       NewLine & "Return 0" & NewLine & "END_CATCH:" & NewLine & "Return 1" & NewLine & "END_TRY: ", SQLConn)
                    If MASQLComm.Connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                        MASQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Else
                        MASQLComm.Connection.Open()
                        MASQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End If
            End Select
            Success = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Class 'DB_Access' CreateSP ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
            Success = False
        End Try
        MASQLComm.Connection.Close()

    End Sub
```

And here is a code for use to run the above procedure:

```
Public Shared Sub RunSP(ByVal DrivePath As String, ByVal DBname As String, ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Try

             DBConnection("SQLConn", "SQLUSER", "master", False, sender, e)
            MASQLComm = New SqlCommand("EXEC dbo." & procName & " '" & DBname & " '", SQLConn)
        MASQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MASQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MASQLComm = New SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE " & DBname & " SET RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", SQLConn)
            MASQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Success = True
        Catch qx As SqlException
            MessageBox.Show(qx.Message, "Class 'NainClass' Run Stored Procdure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
            Success = False
        End Try

        MASQLComm.Connection.Close()
    End Sub
```

And here is a code for SQLconn connectionstring:

```
 If Not CBool(SQLConn.State) Then
                                SQLConn.ConnectionString = "server=" & ServNameKeyValue & "; Uid=" & cUserName & ";  Pwd=" & cUserPass & "; database=" & DBname
                                SQLConn.Open()
                            Else
                                SQLConn.Close()
                                SQLConn.ConnectionString = "server=" & ServNameKeyValue & "; Uid=" & cUserName & ";  Pwd=" & cUserPass & "; database=" & DBname
                                SQLConn.Open()
                            End If
```